# Chained Select Menu works great, but requires small tweak

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select, menu

Currently I have my chained select menus working great.

However currently when the page loads **the first dropdown menu is completely empty**.

I would prefer to populate the  menu initially with ALL the results from:
**SELECT * FROM employees** and then if the user chooses an option from 2nd dropdown, it would then initiate the AJAX and filter the results based on the selection.

Is this possible?

Here are my files:

**dept_form.html (HTML Form) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Employees by Department</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="dept.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "style.css";</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- dept_form_ajax.html -->
<p>Select a department and click 'GO' to see the employees in that department.</p>
<form action="" method="get" id="dept_form">
<select id="results"></select>
<p>
<select id="did" name="did">
<option value="1">Human Resources</option>
<option value="2">Accounting</option>
<option value="3">Marketing</option>
<option value="4">Redundancy Department</option>
</select>
</p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js :**

```
// ajax.js

/*  This page defines a function for creating an Ajax request object.
 *  This page should be included by other pages that 
 *  need to perform an XMLHttpRequest.
 */

/*  Function for creating the XMLHttpRequest object.
 *  Function takes no arguments.
 *  Function returns a browser-specific XMLHttpRequest object
 *  or returns the Boolean value false.
 */
function getXMLHttpRequestObject() {

    // Initialize the object:
    var ajax = false;

    // Choose object type based upon what's supported:
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        // IE 7, Mozilla, Safari, Firefox, Opera, most browsers:
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE browsers

        // Create type Msxml2.XMLHTTP, if possible:
        try {
            ajax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) { // Create the older type instead:
            try {
                ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) { }
        }

    } // End of main IF-ELSE IF.

    // Return the value:
    return ajax;

} // End of getXMLHttpRequestObject() function.
```

**dept.js :**

```
// dept.js

/*  This page does all the magic for applying
 *  Ajax to an employees listing form.
 *  The department_id is sent to a PHP 
 *  script which will return data in HTML format.
 */

// Have a function run after the page loads:
window.onload = init;

// Function that adds the Ajax layer:
function init() {

  // Get an XMLHttpRequest object:
  var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

  // Attach the function call to the form submission, if supported:
  if (ajax) {

    // Check for DOM support:
    if (document.getElementById('results')) {

      // Add an onsubmit event handler to the form:
      $('#did').change(function() {

        // Call the PHP script.
        // Use the GET method.
        // Pass the department_id in the URL.

        // Get the department_id:
        var did = document.getElementById('did').value;

        // Open the connection:
        ajax.open('get', 'dept_results_ajax.php?did=' + encodeURIComponent(did));

        // Function that handles the response:
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
          // Pass it this request object:
          handleResponse(ajax);
        }

        // Send the request:
        ajax.send(null);

        return false; // So form isn't submitted.

      } // End of anonymous function.

    )} // End of DOM check.

  } // End of ajax IF.

} // End of init() function.

// Function that handles the response from the PHP script:
function handleResponse(ajax) {

  // Check that the transaction is complete:
  if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

    // Check for a valid HTTP status code:
    if ((ajax.status == 200) || (ajax.status == 304) ) {

      // Put the received response in the DOM:
      var results = document.getElementById('results');
      results.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

      // Make the results box visible:
      results.style.display = 'block';

    } else { // Bad status code, submit the form.
      document.getElementById('dept_form').submit();
    }

  } // End of readyState IF.

} // End of handleResponse() function.
```

**dept_results_ajax.php**

```
<?php # dept_results_ajax.php

// No need to make a full HTML document!

// Validate the received department ID:
$did = 0; // Initialized value.
if (isset($_GET['did'])) { // Received by the page.
  $did = (int) $_GET['did']; // Type-cast to int.
}

// Make sure the department ID is a positive integer:
if ($did > 0) {

  // Get the employees from the database...

  // Include the database connection script:
  require_once('mysql.inc.php');

  // Query the database:
  $q = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE department_id=$did ORDER BY last_name, first_name";
  $r = mysql_query($q, $dbc);

  // Check that some results were returned:
  if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {

    // Retrieve the results:
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['last_name']; ?>"><?php echo $row['last_name']; ?></option>
      <?php
    } // End of WHILE loop.

  } else { // No employees.
    echo '<p class="error">There are no employees listed for the given department.</p>';
  }

  // Close the database connection.
  mysql_close($dbc);

} else { // Invalid department ID!
  echo '<p class="error">Please select a valid department from the drop-down menu in order to view its employees.</p>';
}

?>
```

Can someone explain the change I need to make in my scripts to achieve what I require.

Many thanks for any pointers. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways: first, you can have a PHP script generate dept_form.html (which would then become a .php file, of course) and put all the results from your MySQL query into the menu; the second (and preferred, especially for large data sets) approach would be to insert a few lines after `if (document.getElementById('results')) {` in dept.js to load all the data, so even before setting the function on `$('#did').change` events. These lines would then simply make an AJAX call to the PHP script and get all the data you need.

By the way, you may want to consider using jQuery, which will make your life a lot easier in terms of AJAX calls. Hope this helps a bit.

**EDIT**

Try using something like this:

```
// Open the connection:
ajax.open('get', 'dept_results_ajax.php');

// Function that handles the response:
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // Pass it this request object:
    handleResponse(ajax);
}

// Send the request:
ajax.send(null);
```

Then, in your PHP script, just put the same code you already have under the `else` clause, except for the parts that are needed for processing the department ID, so pretty much whenever you have `$did` or a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Many thanks, Daan. I do realise it was quite a lot to take in so I appreciate you getting this far :-) Good call on jQuery too. Can you possibly show me how I load all the data before setting the the function on $('#did').change? Sorry if I seem a bit newb-like, but I am fairly new to AJAX/Javascript. Would really appreciate the help here. Thanks again.

Comment: Is it simply a case of adding a `ajax.open('get', '....` line before the `$('#did').change` part? This time not carrying any query string value? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Yes, in terms of the AJAX call, that's what you need to do. You'll need to tweak your PHP script a bit, though, because currently it checks whether a valid department ID has been passed on:
  
    `if ($did > 0) {
    //return data
    } else { // Invalid department ID!
    //show error message
    }`

Now, you could either add an "elseif($did == 0)" and put the `SELECT * FROM table` there, or you could use a separate GET term, e.g. dept_results_ajax.php?all=true, and then test for that. That's really a matter of personal preference, I'd say (and I'd prefer the latter, being a bit clearer.)

Comment: Thanks, Daan. Will try this out shortly. Thanks again for your detail and patience here while I stumble my way through JS :)

Comment: Now I think about it, Would it not make more sense for my PHP to be: `if ($did > 0) { //return data } else { // retrieve ALL results }`? I'm just not sure how to amend my 'dept.js' file to initially populate the select menu. Can you show me an example using my code above?

Comment: Something like the code I just added in my edit should work :) Two more things, by the way: this code will break if there is anyone in your database whose name includes double quotes or any HTML special characters, so you may want to put the data you're getting from MySQL through something like `addslashes` or `htmlspecialchars` before you put it into the HTML. Otherwise you could end up with something like `<option value="John "The Man" Doe">` which would break the HTML. Also, you could use Second, you could just use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array + MYSQL_ASSOC :) Good luck!

Comment: That's brilliant, Daan. I'll get access to the server to make the alts in about an hour. Will post back with how I get on. You're too kind.